# SQL Server 2012 Database Change via Executable/Install file?

Tags: sql, installation, executable

The software I am responsible for uses a SQL Server 2012 database. There are about 10 different servers. All of which are offline and disconnected from each other. The software and database are designed to be completely offline. Basically all 10 servers are just a mirror of a master development server.

The problem I have is updating the database of any structural changes made. When the database structure is modified I need a easy way of updating the 10 other servers with the `CREATE/DELETE/ETC` statements which were done on the development server.

My question is if there is easy way of updating the 10 offline servers? I'd like to create a SQL document with all the changes that were made and make some sort of a Install out of it which the people in charge of the other servers can run to implement the changes.

Comment: Found it. It's done using SQLCMD on the cmd line. I can use this with a SQL Script and Batch file.

Answer (score 0):

It's done using SQLCMD on the cmd line. I can use this with a SQL Script and Batch file.